# Solving the matrix differential equation $v'(z) = A e^z + B v(z), v'(0) = 0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Take the system of ODEs in terms of the scalar $z$,

$$v'(z) = A e^z + B\cdot v(z)$$
With the initial condition,
$$v'(0) = \mathbf{0}$$

For some $B$ an $N \times N$ matix, and $A$ a $1\times N$ vector, $\mathbf{0}$ is a $1\times N$ vector of $0$'s, and $v(z)$ a $1\times N$ vector.  Assume whatever you need for the eigenvalues/vectors of $B$, etc.

My question is: what is the solution $v(z)$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?  I know how to do it by diagonalizing, getting eigenvectors, etc. for a particular set of matrices/vectors but would rather have it in terms of matrix exponentials.  The homogeneous part of the equation is pretty simple in this case, but I am not sure how to do the inhomogeneous part.

(as an addendum to this question, is there a handbook of ODEs that has good coverage of matrix differenital equations?)

**Following through on the answer:**
It appears that the solution is,
$$v(z) = e^{B z}\cdot\int_{0}^{z}e^{-B s}\cdot A e^s ds + e^{B s}\cdot C$$
Using the properties a property of matrix exponentials(not proven, see notes)
$$=e^{B z}\cdot\left(\int_{0}^z e^{(I - B)s}ds\right) \cdot A + e^{B s}\cdot C$$
Evaluating the integral,
$$=e^{B z}\cdot(I - B)^{-1}\cdot(e^{(I-B)z}-I)\cdot A + e^{B s}\cdot C$$
Reorganizing a little
$$v(z)=e^{B z}\cdot\left(C - (I - B)^{-1}\cdot A + (I - B)^{-1}\cdot e^{(I - B)z}\cdot A \right)$$
Take the derivative with the product rule for matrix differentiation,
$$
v'(z) = e^{B z}(I - B)^{-1}(I - B) e^{(I - B)z} A + B e^{B z}\left(C - (I - B)^{-1}\cdot A + (I - B)^{-1}\cdot e^{(I - B)z}\cdot A \right)
$$
Use $v'(0) = 0$
$$
0 = A + B(C - (I - B)^{-1}A + (I - B)^{-1} A)
$$
Solve for $C$,
$$C = -B^{-1} A
$$
Finally, substitute back into $v(z)$
$$
v(z) = e^{B z}\left((I - B)^{-1}e^{(I - B)z} - B^{-1} - (I - B)^{-1} \right)A
$$
Simplifying a little more,
$$
v(z) = e^{B z}(I - B)^{-1}\left(e^{(I - B)z} - B^{-1}\right)A
$$
Does that look right?

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/744324/55235) answer of mine is what you want.

Comment: Wait, is the boldfaced $0$ a $1$xN or an NxN vector?

Comment: Sorry, a vector of zeros of the appropriate length

Comment: Are you sure you want the initial condition $v'(0) = 0$ and not $v(0)= 0$?  The latter is far more common . . .

Comment: Definitely $v'(0)=0$

Comment: OK, $v'(0) = 0$ it is!  Thanks!

Comment: Just another comment similar to @GitGud's answer. Have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807847/electricity-differential-equation-problem/807854#807854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness:

Let $v(t) \in \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that:

$$v'(t) - b \, v(t) = f(t),$$ where $b$ is a constant and $f(t) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function of $t$. The solution of this equation can be obtained in terms of an integrating factor, $I(t) \neq 0$, which satisfies:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}(I(t) v(t)) = I(t) f(t).$$ It is relatively simple to see that $$I(t) = \exp\left(- \int b \, \mathrm{d}t\right).$$ Then, from the equation above, it yields:

$$ v(t) = C \frac{1}{I(t)} +\frac{1}{I(t)} \int^t_0 I(t) f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = C e^{-bt}+e^{-bt} \int^t_0 e^{bt} f(t) \,  \mathrm{d} t,$$ where the initial condition remains to be imposed (indeed, note that $v'(t) = b \, v(t) + f(t)$) in order to obtain the value of the constant of integration, $C$.

Note that, in the link I [give you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807847/electricity-differential-equation-problem/807854#807854), $I(t)$ becomes a matrix, $v$ becomes a vector, $b$ is actually a matrix, $f$ becomes a vector, $1/I$ becomes matrix inversion, $\exp$ becomes matrix exponential... so there's a nice correspondence between the 1D case and the $n$-D case that I hope is useful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The correspondence to the 1D case is great, but I have had lots of trouble ensuring that there were no ordering errors due to the non-commutative rules.  See my comments working through in my question and where I get stuck.

Comment: Hi there @jlperla, the steps look good, but I can't see why you introduce the $I$ (unit) matrix. Excuse me if this follows from some basics of algebra.

Comment: $e^z e^{-B z} = e^{(I - B)z}$ when verified with generic 2x2 matrices in mathematica.  I couldn't figure it out a complete proof, but I think it is because of some identity with the eigenvalues here: $eig(-B) + [1,1] = eig(I - B)$ which you can use with the eigen-decomposition definitino of the matrix exponential

Comment: and others, this seemed to be far too easy for you.  If you want a bigger challenge, see my other question on matrix ODEs: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811491